# How to access shortcut for Add To Contact screen for mobile phone

Tags: php, jquery, html, hyperlink

I'm working on digital business card. 
I want to open `Add To Contact` screen from a mobile phone using an `HTML5` button link.  I can't find out a way to do it using `HTML5`.

I'm able to find and use the shortcuts for telephone, SMS, email, etc.  But, how do I access the shortcut for the `Add To Contact` screen?

For example, here are the shortcuts I'm using for telephone and SMS:

```
<p class="mobile"><a href="tel://1<? echo $phone; ?>" class="button2"><? echo $phoneNo; ?></a></p>
<p class="mobile"><a href="sms://1<? echo $phone; ?>" class="button2"><? echo $phoneNo; ?></a></p>
```

What is the syntax for the `Add To Contact` screen?

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: I want to open add to contact screen of mobile phone using HTML5 Button link. Inshort accessing contact of mobile phone using HTML5.

Comment: that is a statement no question...

Comment: It is a question brother. there are shortcut for phone call and sms in html like tel , sms etc. But for open add to contact screen i can't figure out any way

Comment: `tel:` and `sms:` are the only widely-used mobile-related URI commands. There is no protocol to open a Contacts application on someone's phone from a web page.

Comment: @JonUleis.  ohk thank you for your answer . So i have to integrate PhoneGap api or any other for this ?  because it's very small functionality so phone gap integration is very big options for this small functionality.

Comment: I don't believe PhoneGap or any API would accomplish the ability to open a phone Contacts app. Googling shows that recent versions of iOS and Android may support the ability to import contact information from a .VCF (VCard) file, so maybe experiment with that route.

Comment: @JonUleis. Ohk great may be that will be the solution. thank you for showing me the path of work. let you know when i will complete this experiment.

Comment: I've added a specific question, and clarified the context.

Comment: @devlincarnate. thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all of you for your help but finally i figure it out that **It is not possible**.

Link of attempt : http://www.w3.org/TR/contacts-api/

> The Contacts Intent section in HTML5 specification was an attempt to a
>   uniform view to the contacts; an implementation which varied across
>   multiple operating systems and web applications. Users had to maintain
>   multiple sets of same address book information since there was nothing
>   available to tie it together, resulting in redundant and often stale
>   information.

I also tried codes of this link : https://www.w3.org/TR/web-intents/

But i figure it out that it would be horrible if that was possible due to security restrictions of mobile phone.